# Call GraphQL endpoints using Cypress .request

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, graphql, graphql-js, cypress

I have googled `cypress request with graphql` but I see lots of people mentioning `mock up server`, `stub` and so on.  But I am not able to find a ful example of how to use GraphQL with [cy.request](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Syntax).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

maybe you can this this try when using `cy.request` pretty much like the usual way you use `restful` in `cy.request`

example your query name is `findUser` with variable of `username`
your query should look something like `findUser(username:"hello"){id, name}` and so on

but instead of just this, you need to pass it as `json` if it is a query then it'll be `{"query": findUser(username:"hello"){id, name}}`  this will actually be your body.

an example is below...

```
const query = `{
  findUser(username:"hello") {
    id
  }
}`;
    
cy.request({
  url: 'http://localhost/graphql/',  // graphql endpoint
  body: { query },                   // or { query: query } depending if you are writing with es6
  failOnStatusCode: false            // not a must but in case the fail code is not 200 / 400
}).then((res) => {
  cy.log(res);
});
```

Comment: nice this does work, thx a lot. I even tried using `graphql-request` which doesn't work as good as expected

Comment: Were you able to have this work with a mutation? I can't seem to work it out. Any ideas?

Comment: @jamesemanon this works with mutation too, the same as query.  Do you want to make a post so I can give you sample codes?

Comment: Yeah, that would be great if you could! Also, I'm trying to figure out how to do a react-dropzone "click" image upload. This seems to be an issue with cypress, no?

Comment: @jamesemanon give me the URL of your question post so I can give you a sample code. As for image upload, I am not that far yet but maybe you can take a look at these two posts which I hope would help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074225/how-to-test-file-inputs-with-cypress and https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012988/cypress-w-graphql-having-issues-getting-auth-with-testing-via-ui-better-way-t

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer worked for me as soon as I added `method: "post"`

```
const query = `
  query getItems {
    items {
      items {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

cy.request({
  method: "post",
  url: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  body: { query },
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.body);
});
```