# Cypress is not uploading the image

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am automating one of the use cases in cypress and I am unable to upload the image using attach file function.
Below is the code and the snippets from HTML tags

UI Upload Image

[image: UI Upload Image]

HTML tags

[image: HTML tags]

VS code

[image: VS code]

Comment: check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074225/how-to-test-file-inputs-with-cypress

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's better to paste in the test and HTML as text rather than images, because it makes it easier to write an answer by copy/paste and modify for corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to attach the file to the `<input>` as a first step. Then click the button, or you may not even have to do the click().

From the docs,

```js
// start watching the POST requests
cy.intercept({ method: 'POST', url: /upload_endpoint/ }).as('upload');

const myFilePath = 'product.jpeg'; // file is in "/cypress/fixtures/" folder

cy.fixture(myFilePath, 'binary')
  .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
  .then(fileContent => {
    cy.get('input#productImageUpload').attachFile({
      fileContent,
      fileName: myFilePath,
      mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
      encoding:'utf8',
      lastModified: new Date().getTime(
    })
  })

cy.get('.label-side').click()   // may not need to do this

// wait for the 'upload_endpoint' request, and leave a 2 minutes delay before throwing an error
cy.wait('@upload', { requestTimeout: 120000 });
```

Comment: It threw the same error which I was facing with my code. It says the path or name is missing but I am unable to understand why it is throwing the same error even after giving the path.

Error from cypress:

missing "filePath" or "fileName".
Please make sure you are passing either "filePath" or "fileName"

Comment: Ok, the error about the file path means `/fixtures/product.jpeg` should be changed to `product.jpeg`. Maybe that's all you need to change in your original code. I assumed it was something to do with encoding.

Comment: Also, looks like the `fileName` parameter can be anything, or even omitted.

Comment: I tried with all the possibilities but it still throws the same error.