# Cypress: How to attachFile from different folder

Tags: cypress

I have to upload a file from a different folder than /fixtures.
If I use attachFile it always adds the path cypress/fixtures in front of it.

```
cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile(this.uploadFileName );
        cy.get('#file-submit').click();
```

Where this.uploadFileName has an absolute path to the file.

The file is generated before, so it is not really a fixture anyway.

Comment: I think attachFile expects the file to be placed in the fixtures folder, also referring to the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58948308/6135684. If you say the file is generated before, then maybe you can copy it to the fixtures folder after it is created and then call attachFile.

Comment: Yes, that is one solution. I don't like it, though. It is not a fixture! And I can't believe that it is not possible to change the folders?!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, attachFile can only import file from the fixtures folder. Hence, the generated file has to be imported into the fixture file (via task and fs.copy()).